# Is there a shortcut to merge the previously selected Git branch into the current one?

Tags: git, github

`git checkout -` switches to previously selected branch. Is there any such shortcut to merge previously selected branch?

Answer (score 2):

Yes; `git merge -` will also work. The full form is `@{-1}`; you can also do things like `@{-5}` to get the fifth most recent ref you were on.

If you like, you can read more on [git's revision shortcuts](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).